# API to resize an image after selected from gallery or camera

Tags: android, image, resize

I have an application that lets the user select an image from the gallery or from the phone's camera. This image is then used as image on an image button.

I was wondering if there was any built in API that I could use prompt an image resize intent that lets the user resize the image.

The idea would be only to allow squared images to make the display easier afterwards in the app. By having this "resizer" the user would choose which part of his picture will be selected.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Bitmap class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

and use the function:
createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was any built in API that I could use prompt an image resize intent that lets the user resize the image.

There is no such standard `Intent` action in the Android SDK.

It may be that you are really looking for image cropping, not resizing. That too is not part of the Android SDK, though [there are libraries for that](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: Yes cropping was the word I was looking for!
I will take a look at the link you have given! thanks!